# Linq2sql Connection string for crystal report. Report requires logon

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-4.0, linq-to-sql, crystal-reports

If I take out the connection string info the report runs fine from my machine but any other user it asks for logon information so I am trying to add the connection info. The line that is not compiling is `cr1.SetDatabaseLogon(connection, cr1);`

What am I doing wrong? Any help would be appreciated!

```
private void launchReport(int pKReport)
{
    using (DataClasses1DataContext db = new DataClasses1DataContext())
    {
        var query = (from s in db.expenseHdrs
                     join d in db.expenseDtls on s.rptNo equals d.rptNo
                     where s.rptNo == pKReport
                     from g in db.employees
                     join r in db.expenseHdrs on g.pk equals r.empPk
                     select new
                     {
                         s.period,
                         s.description,
                         s.department,
                         s.rptNo,
                         s.reimbursement, g.name, 
                         d.expDate,
                         d.expType,
                         d.expDesc
                     });

        CrystalReport1 cr1 = new CrystalReport1();

        ConnectionInfo connection = new ConnectionInfo();
        connection.DatabaseName = "intranet";
        connection.UserID = "sa";
        connection.Password = "*****";
        cr1.SetDatabaseLogon(connection, cr1);

        cr1.SetDataSource(query);
        crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = cr1;
    }
}
```

I also tried changing the code after my query to below but I still have the exact same problem as before when I didnt have the connection string credentials. On every user but myself I get the same sql server login screen and no matter what I enter it fails. I think it is due to there being no database name which it will not allow me to manually enter.

```
 CrystalReport1 cr1 = new CrystalReport1();
            cr1.FileName = @"C:\Intranet\CrystalReport1.rpt";

            ConnectionInfo connectionInfo = new ConnectionInfo();
            connectionInfo.ServerName = "svr-sql";
            connectionInfo.DatabaseName = "intranet";
            connectionInfo.UserID = "sa";
            connectionInfo.Password = "*****";

            SetDBLogonForReport(connectionInfo, cr1);
            cr1.SetDataSource(query);
            crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = cr1;
        }
    }

private void SetDBLogonForReport(ConnectionInfo connectionInfo, CrystalReport reportDocument)
    {
        Tables tables = reportDocument.Database.Tables;
        foreach (CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Table table in tables)
        {
            TableLogOnInfo tableLogonInfo = table.LogOnInfo;
            tableLogonInfo.ConnectionInfo = connectionInfo;
            table.ApplyLogOnInfo(tableLogonInfo);
        }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Can you log in to the other databases using that username and password combo if you use sql server management studio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a straight sql datasource was the issue. I had to change it to OLE DB(ADO) for sql server to get it to work. Oh crystal reports....

Answer (score 1):

```
CrystalReport1 cr1 = new CrystalReport1();
    cr1.FileName = @"C:\Intranet\CrystalReport1.rpt";

    ConnectionInfo connectionInfo = new ConnectionInfo();
    connectionInfo.ServerName = "svr-sql";
    connectionInfo.DatabaseName = "intranet";
    connectionInfo.UserID = "sa";
    connectionInfo.Password = "*****";


    //add this code 

    connectionInfo.IntegratedSecurity = false;

.........................
```